# SagePay form integration BillingSurname is too long

Tags: php, opayo

I have managed to get my server talking to the SagePAY server using PHP with Form integration.
My name-value-pairs are constructed, strung together, encrypted and are being posted to SagePAY where they are being accepted.

However, SagePAY server response is stating that the ***BillingSurname*** is too long (error 3108).  BillingSurname is built and delivered in exactly the same way as BillingForenames and did have the same data in it. I have tried just sending "Smith" through instead and it is still 'too long'.  Needless to say it is less than the 20 chars specified.

Any ideas anyone?

Edit: Adding the code that encrypts - although I don't think that is the problem - been through that already as the server is now reading TXCode, Currency, Amount etc until we reach the Billing Address.

```
<?php
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
    $key = "SagePAY encryption key here";
    $iv = $key;

    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

        $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
    }
    return $enc;
}
$str = "VendorTxCode=13362020&Currency=GBP&Description=a-url.co.uk Personalised stationery&SuccessURL=http://a-url.co.uk/success/&FailureURL=http://a-url.co.uk/problem/&VendorEmail=email@a-url.co.uk&SendEmail=1&Amount=7.95&BillingFirstnames=Albert&BillingSurname=Smith&BillingEmail=email@a-url.co.uk&BillingAddress1=4drds&BillingAddress2=deldSurrey&BillingCity=ddcd&BillingPostCode=XX7 1XX&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=01342 123456&DeliveryFirstnames=Albert&DeliverySurname=Smith&DeliveryAddress1=4drds&DeliveryAddress2=deldSurrey&DeliveryCity=ddcd&DeliveryPostCode=AB7 6RF&DeliveryCountry=GB"
$datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
$cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);
?>
```

Comment: Encoding issues ? Also please show us the code that submits the form.

Comment: Your title and edit message say this is resolved - you should post what you did as an answer and accept it, so that other people facing this problem in the future can see it easily.

Comment: OP, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I had inadvertently added an extra field that was not in the specification - BillingEmail. That caused the SagePAY error on BillingSurname.